# How can I cancel a Rest operation in androidannotations

Tags: android-annotations

I've read throughout the whole document and find no answer to that.

Is there anyway I can cancel a rest operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Spring Rest-Template does not provide this feature.